# Find last row index in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a loop on a sheet of another workbook but the last row index line of code seems not to be working.

The last row index of the B column on the sheet "AD CAPITAL" of the opened workbook "Inventaire des OPCVM -AMMC.xls" is needed for the loop on index I. That line is supposed to return the last row index but it returns an error

> The index does not belong to the selection

```
Sub Transpariser()

Workbooks("d05_MARCHE.xlsx").Sheets("Feuil1").Activate

Dim i, j, m, k, z, l As Integer
m = 0
i=0
j=0
k=0
z=0
l=0

Dim n As Worksheet
Set n = Sheets("Feuil1")

Dim v As Workbook
Set v = Workbooks("Inventaire des OPCVM -AMMC.xls")

n.Range("A1").Value = "Titres"

For j = 2 To 114

    '***This is the line of code where it kept bugging***
    l = v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row    

    For i = 1 To l

        If v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Feuil3").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            m = i
            Set n = v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL")
        End If
    Next i
...
```

Comment: Also `but it doesnt work` is not enough of an explanation of what the error is.  Please explain more what it is doing that it should not.

Comment: Thanks  Scott Craner I did what u mentionned is it Alright now??

Comment: You still have not explained what it is doing that is wrong.  Is throwing an error, is it not returning the correct row?  What is the problem with that line?

Comment: If it is an error, what error is thrown?

Comment: it returns an error saying "The index does not belong to the selection"

Comment: Then your sheet name is incorrect, or spelled wrong. `AD CAPITAL` is not a sheet on `Inventaire des OPCVM -AMMC.xls`

Comment: I dont know how it could be spelled wrong ,I copied the sheet name from the workbook

Comment: Then check the name of the workbook. And make sure it is an .xls and not a .xlsx or .xlsm

Comment: I started by doing that ,I verified  it now its an xls and the name of the workbook was copied

Comment: Then sorry, but I am out of suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your interest ,I think the issue might  be coming from other lines before that one like declaration of workbook

Comment: Your `Rows.Count` will be `1048576` as your active workbook is an `xlsx` file.  So your `v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL").Cells(Rows.Count, 2)` is referring to cell B1048576 in a sheet in a `xls` file which only has 65536 rows.  See the answer from Mahmoud Mostafa.

Answer (score 1):

Like So:

```
l = v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL").Cells(v.Sheets("AD CAPITAL").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: That's what i was trying to say. Thanks!